# Update user stories description in bulk in rally

Tags: rally

Is there a way to update all US description using excel add-in or some other way?

Say for example - I have 100 US and i want to update the description of the US with same name as US

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the excel add-in probably, yes.  That's probably the easiest.  You could also do it with a custom list app by selecting the items and bulk editing them.

Comment: No. Bulk edit does not work for description. If you have done it throught excel or bulk edit, please share here.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little custom app I put together:
https://github.com/krmorse/BulkEditDescription

It's a list of stories and includes the advanced filtering component so you can find what you're looking for.  Then just bulk edit description on your selected stories.

Just paste this html into a custom html app and you should be good to go:
https://github.com/krmorse/BulkEditDescription/blob/master/deploy/App-uncompressed.html